# Error: property map doesn't exist on type 'Observable<Response>'

Tags: node.js, angular, rxjs

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

this part is not working. can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: property map doesn't exist on type 'Observable<Response>'

Comment: What Angular & RxJS versions you have?

Comment: You need to post more code including your angular and` rxjs` version?

Comment: "rxjs": "^6.2.1", angular "^6.0.3"

Comment: import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getShoppingItems() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/items').map(res => res.json());
  }

}

this is the whole code

Comment: Everything is explained here: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `HttpModule` which is **deprecated** you should use **[HttpClientModule](https://angular.io/guide/http)** instead
Regarding the error

> property map doesn't exist on type 'Observable'

`RxJS v5.5.2+` has moved to **[Pipeable](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md)** operators to improve tree shaking and make it easier to create custom operators.
 now `operators` need to be  combined using the `pipe` method
**[Refer This](https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-understanding-lettable-operators-fe74dda186d3)**
**New Import**

```
import { map} from 'rxjs/operators';
```

**Example**

```
myObservable
  .pipe(map(data => data * 2),)
  .subscribe(...);
```

**Modified code**

```
    getShoppingItems() { return this.http.get('localhost:3000/api/items')
    .pipe(map(res => res.json())); } }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! you helped me a lot. God bless you :)

Comment: Glad I could help Mate can you make it as a correct answer:)